# Pandas - how to sum X last values from 2 columns based on the condition

Tags: pandas, numpy, data-science

Recently I started to learn Pandas. I really tried to get the solution, but couldn't find it. Here's the issue.

I have a data frame: simple football data.
For each team I'd like to know how many goals they scored in their previous 2 matches; regardless if they were home or away team. So I have to sum a specific number of values from 2 different columns for each team.

Sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['2018-02-03', 'manutd', 'chelsea', 3, 1], ['2018-02-08', 'arsenal', 'liverpool', 1, 1], 
        ['2018-01-12', 'chelsea', 'westham', 2, 0], ['2018-01-12', 'liverpool', 'manutd', 0, 2], 
        ['2018-03-15', 'arsenal', 'chelsea', 2, 2], ['2018-02-20', 'manutd', 'brighton', 0, 0], 
        ['2018-04-01', 'westham', 'fulham', 1, 0], ['2018-03-15', 'manutd', 'westham', 2, 1]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['event_time', 'home_team', 'away_team', 'home_goals', 'away_goals'])
df['event_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['event_time'])
df.sort_values(['event_time'],inplace=True, ascending=False)
print(df)


  event_date  home_team  away_team  home_goals  away_goals
6 2018-04-01    westham     fulham           1           0
4 2018-03-15    arsenal    chelsea           2           2
7 2018-03-15     manutd    westham           2           1
5 2018-02-20     manutd   brighton           0           0
1 2018-02-08    arsenal  liverpool           1           1
0 2018-02-03     manutd    chelsea           3           1
2 2018-01-12    chelsea    westham           2           0
3 2018-01-12  liverpool     manutd           0           2
```

What I want to achieve:

```
  event_time  home_team  away_team  home_goals  away_goals  h_goals_previous_2  a_goals_previous_2
6 2018-04-01    westham     fulham           1           0                  1                  NaN
4 2018-03-15    arsenal    chelsea           2           2                  1                    3
7 2018-03-15     manutd    westham           2           1                  3                    0
5 2018-02-20     manutd   brighton           0           0                  5                  NaN
1 2018-02-08    arsenal  liverpool           1           1                NaN                    0
0 2018-02-03     manutd    chelsea           3           1                  2                      2
2 2018-01-12    chelsea    westham           2           0                NaN                  NaN
3 2018-01-12  liverpool     manutd           0           2                NaN                  NaN
```

Description: 
- on 2018-03-15 Arsenal played with Chelsea. In the previous 2 matches Chelsea scored 3 goals in total: 1 when they were away team and 2 when they were home team. 
- some of the previous goals are Nan because we don't have data for previous matches.

I was trying to do it by iterating team by team and for each team I was building a sorted subset of df, then could aggregate the values, but feel it's not the best solution and it can be done using nice Pandas expression:

```
teams = pd.unique(df[['home_team', 'away_team']].values.ravel('K'))
for team in teams:
    print(team)
    team_df = df[(df['home_team']==team) | (df['away_team']==team)]
    team_df.sort_values(['event_date'],inplace=True, ascending=False)
    print(team_df)
```

How can I do it without writing loops and ifs?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "doesn't matter if they were home or away team"? If that's true, then why do you have two `goals_previous_2` columns. One for home, and one for away. Also, if you want quicker feedback I'd suggest completing both of those columns with desired output.

Comment: The output is updated. There are 2 `goals_previous_2` because I want to calculate it for home team and away team and how many goals they scored in previous 2 matches.
Description of calculations: 
- on 2018-03-15 Arsenal played with Chelsea. In the previous 2 matches Chelsea scored 3 goals in total: 1 when they were away team and 2 when they were home team. 
- some of the previous goals are Nan because we don't have data for previous matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1:[`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html):**

```
#Create a df2 with index like a column a rename the columns to apply:
# pd.wide_to_long

df2=df.set_index('event_time',append=True)
df2.columns=[''.join(name[::-1]) for name in  df2.columns.str.split('_')]
df2.columns=df2.columns.str.replace('home','1').str.replace('away','2')
df2=df2.reset_index()

#Using pd.wide_to_long
df_long=( pd.wide_to_long(df2,['team','goals'],i='level_0',j='key')
          .sort_values('event_time',ascending=False) )
print(df_long)


            event_time       team  goals
level_0 key                             
6       1   2018-04-01    westham      1
        2   2018-04-01     fulham      0
4       1   2018-03-15    arsenal      2
7       1   2018-03-15     manutd      2
4       2   2018-03-15    chelsea      2
7       2   2018-03-15    westham      1
5       1   2018-02-20     manutd      0
        2   2018-02-20   brighton      0
1       1   2018-02-08    arsenal      1
        2   2018-02-08  liverpool      1
0       1   2018-02-03     manutd      3
        2   2018-02-03    chelsea      1
2       1   2018-01-12    chelsea      2
3       1   2018-01-12  liverpool      0
2       2   2018-01-12    westham      0
3       2   2018-01-12     manutd      2
```

---

```
#calculating the sum
groups_goals=df_long.groupby('team')['goals']
df_long=df_long.assign(value_2_sum=groups_goals.shift(-1)+groups_goals.shift(-2))

#Getting goals previous columns
goals_previous=df_long.pivot_table(index='level_0',columns='key',values='value_2_sum',dropna=False)

df[['h_goals_previous_2',  'a_goals_previous_2']]=goals_previous
print(df)
```

**Method 2: [`DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt)**

```
cols=['h_goals_previous_2',  'a_goals_previous_2']
df2=( df.reset_index()
        .melt(['event_time','home_team','away_team','index'])
        .sort_values('event_time',ascending=False) )
df2['team']=df2['home_team'].mask(df2['variable'].eq('away_goals'),df2['away_team'])
```

---

```
groups_goals=df2.groupby('team')['value']

df2['value_2']=groups_goals.shift(-2)+groups_goals.shift(-1)
df[cols]=( df2.pivot_table(columns='variable',index='index',values='value_2',dropna=False)
              .sort_index(axis=1,ascending=False) )
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
  event_time  home_team  away_team  home_goals  away_goals  \
6 2018-04-01    westham     fulham           1           0   
4 2018-03-15    arsenal    chelsea           2           2   
7 2018-03-15     manutd    westham           2           1   
5 2018-02-20     manutd   brighton           0           0   
1 2018-02-08    arsenal  liverpool           1           1   
0 2018-02-03     manutd    chelsea           3           1   
2 2018-01-12    chelsea    westham           2           0   
3 2018-01-12  liverpool     manutd           0           2   

   h_goals_previous_2  a_goals_previous_2  
6                 1.0                 NaN  
4                 NaN                 3.0  
7                 3.0                 NaN  
5                 5.0                 NaN  
1                 NaN                 NaN  
0                 NaN                 NaN  
2                 NaN                 NaN  
3                 NaN                 NaN
```

**Note that there are more NaN values ​​because I have used only the rows shown in your data frame**

Comment: Thanks! It works and I learned a lot. I have a question about parametrizing it for N previous matches, eg. last 8 for large dataset.

Comment: What can be used instead of `value_2_sum=groups_goals.shift(-1)+groups_goals.shift(-2)`? I tried with `groups_goals.shift(-8).rolling(8).sum()`, but doesn't work correctly with groupedby series. If I'm using directly shift&rolling on df['goals'] then it's summing correctly (but it's not what I want to achieve), but after using it for `groups_goals` I get "strange" results - probably an issue with indexes.